# Remove quotation marks and add file extension to filename in a shell script

Tags: shell, filenames

in a shell script I am writing I want to read a filename from another file, remove the quotation marks and add a file extension to it.

```
tmp=$(awk '/output_onefile/ {getline;print}' $cmds_file)
tmp=$(echo "$tmp" | tr -d '"')
uh3dsr_file="${tmp}.sr_uh3d"
```

In the file behind $cmds_file, there is a filename in the line following to "output_onefile". The filename is in quotation marks which I remove in the second line. Up to this, everything works fine.
Then I just want to add .sr_uh3d to the filename.

When I run the code like this and let's say, the filename is "Blabla_123456", I end up with the following:

```
echo "$uh3dsr_file"
.sr_uh3d23456
echo "Text $uh3dsr_file"
.sr_uh3dbla_123456
```

It is putting the .sr_uh3d in front of the rest and overwritting the beginning of the rest.

Can anyone explain that behaviour to me? Is it clear what I am trying to do?

Comment: Can you please add a sample of the input file?

Comment: maybe it would be simpler to do it like this: `uh3dsr_file = echo $tmp".sr_uh3d"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your text file has CRLF line endings, but your tools are expecting LF line endings. Use `dos2unix` beforehand or use `tr` or parameter substitution to strip the CR from the text.

Comment: Thx, you're right. Never thought about it, although I am using dos2unix a little later in the same script.